# Change highlighted section to a specific font style in a txt file

Tags: notepad++, code, visual-styles

I wanted to know if this would be possible with Notepad++ (even if it means downloading plugins).

Suppose I have a `.txt` file. This `.txt` file has some sections that contains some sample C++ code. I wanted to know if it is possible to change the style of the C++ code only (different font and color perhaps) so it appears as code and not just as plain text (as the rest of the document).

I realize that notepad++ is not a super word processor like Microsoft Word but I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Context menu - "Style token". This colores token, ie the word. I cannot color only selected block.

**SynWrite** app can color selected block: install plugin named "Color Text", and make selection.

Answer (score 0):

I used my own custom language and followed this

http://udl20.weebly.com/delimiters.html